# htaccess redirect subdirectory (folder) to single page in same subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I am having another issue with .htaccess where I can't seem to find the right solution for it. What I am trying to accomplish is to redirect from a subdirectory to a specific html document within that **same directory** when you **copy/paste** the url displayed below

For example:
http://example.com/staging/**test/** to http://example.com/staging/**test/page.html**

My (almost) working method:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ test/page.html [L]
```

The problem with this code is that it does basically redirect to the correct **page.html** but if you want to click on any link on page.html it just redirects to page.html again instead of going to a particular link within subdirectory /test/ let's say **/test/page-2.html**

**Important:** This redirect should only affect the subdirectory "staging". All other sub-directories including root can not be affected.

**Other info:**
This code is also in my .htaccess file to remove the .html extension for the directory "staging"

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

The directory "staging" is not connected to any CMS and only consists of .html files.
I am on a shared hosting environment (Hostgator/cPanel).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below rule, you are using only L flag but I am modifying it for redirect as you mentioned.

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^test/$ /staging/test/page.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me a 404 page.

Comment: Where are you using the rule!

Comment: I am using the rule in an .htaccess file placed in subdirectory "test". There is another .htaccess in root. However subdirectory "test" must be completely independent from root.

Comment: What edit are you referring to? I tried your code and it produces a 404 not found. (Link was a mistake.)

Comment: It means I edited my rule did you tried with new rule in my answer!

Comment: You have to check then, if there is some other rule conflicting because above is working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: After your update on your question I've updated my rule, please check if working.

Answer (score 0):

You want to redirect only the directoy, but not the files in it. The pattern in the rule says match the directory `test/` followed by anything `.*`, including any files.

To match the directory alone, the pattern must stop at `test`, which is accomplished by an end of string [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

```
RewriteRule ^test/$ /staging/test/page.html [R,L]
```

---

Instead of an absolute path, you can keep the relative path and add a [`RewriteBase`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive

```
RewriteBase /staging
RewriteRule ^test/$ test/page.html [R,L]
```

---

If you want to rewrite only, leave out the [`R`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag.

Comment: This produces a 404 not found. I assume this happens because the directory "test" does not have an index.html.

Comment: I just looked through the other comments, the .htaccess file is in the subdirectory `test`?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. The .htaccess file is in a directory before "staging". http://example.com/staging/test (You actually provided a solution for me to hide the .html extensions for the same setup)

Comment: Just to clarify, is it `/staging/.htaccess` or `/staging/test/.htaccess` or both?

Comment: It's `/staging/.htaccess`